# All styled components return any (@types/styled-components)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, styled-components

I'm having a weird issue when using styled-components along with VSCode. Below is basically what I get for any components coming from styled-components, they all return any.

[image]
[image]

I got it working before, but can't tell when and I can't see what's wrong in the setup to return any for all the components. I tried to move back to tslint config, removing/commenting out all rules inside the eslintrc files, but couldn't make it work either.

Supprisingly enough, I tried the [starter kit](https://github.com/ueno-llc/react-native-starter) I'm using for my project and the types there are working with the original setup.

[image]

I tried to use the same version of styled-components packages, but still couldn't make it work. Any help, or direction to look at this issue would be very welcomed!

.eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'prettier/@typescript-eslint',
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    project: './tsconfig.json',
    sourceType: 'module',
    ecmaFeatures: { jsx: true },
  },
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', 'react', 'react-native'],
  rules: {
    camelcase: 'off',
    'react/display-name': 'off',
    'react/prop-types': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-ignore': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/camelcase': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': ['error', { argsIgnorePattern: '^_' }],
    '@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/unbound-method': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises': [
      'error',
      {
        checksVoidReturn: false,
      },
    ],
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': ['error', { allowArgumentsExplicitlyTypedAsAny: true }],
  },
  settings: {
    react: {
      pragma: 'React',
      version: 'detect',
    },
  },
  ignorePatterns: ['node_modules/**/*', 'docs/**/*', 'examples/**/*', 'lib/**/*'],
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "typescript-styled-plugin",
        "lint": {
          "validProperties": [
            "shadow-color",
            "shadow-opacity",
            "shadow-offset",
            "shadow-radius",
            "padding-horizontal",
            "padding-vertical",
            "margin-vertical",
            "margin-horizontal",
            "tint-color",
            "aspect-ratio",
            "elevation"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "sourceRoot": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "target": "es2015"
  },
  "include": [".eslintrc.js", "src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx"]
}
```

```
"lint": "yarn format && yarn eslint && yarn stylelint",
"eslint": "tsc -p . --noEmit --skipLibCheck; eslint --fix 'src/**/*.{ts,tsx}'",
...
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "3.8.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "3.8.0",
"eslint": "7.6.0",
"eslint-config-prettier": "6.11.0",
"eslint-plugin-react": "7.20.5",
"eslint-plugin-react-native": "3.8.1",
```

styled.d.ts

```
import 'styled-components';

declare module 'styled-components' {
  // tslint:disable-next-line
  export interface DefaultTheme {
    darkMode: boolean;
    background: string;
    lightBackground: string;
    grayBackground: string;
    darkBackground: string;
    heading: string;
    subheading: string;
    copy: string;
    stroke: string;
    underlay: string;
    map: string;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @jbr, have you found the solution? I have the same problem...

Comment: Nope, I didn't find any solution yet, will dig it up more when I find some spare time

Comment: Same issue here :( I've tried a lot of combos of Typescript/`styled-components`/`@types/styled-components` versions with no luck.

Comment: I won't be able to explain how, but it's working again. I run latest version of vscode, of styled components and eslint dependencies. Not sure what was going on, but it might be an internal issue of of the dependency that were producing this.

Comment: Aw crud. Was hoping for a solution. I do have some older `eslint` dependencies in my project with the issue, so I'll take a pass at starting with a fresh linting setup and see if that's the root cause. Glad you got it fixed!

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved it -
after navigating to the types file of styled-components inside the project I saw this error: `node_modules/hoist-non-react-statics/index"' has no exported member 'NonReactStatics'. ts`

It turned out that I had packages using an older version of hoist-non-react-static, and it was overriding the types being used by styled-components.

upgrading those packages (in my case it was react-redux) solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks!!! In my case it was the `recompose` module.

Answer (score 0):

Types got quietly moved to @types/styled-components-react-native. Still good to update your other dependencies, of course :)

Reference: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/2099